# Cómo pasar excel a array bidimensional usando interop con distintos tipos de datos

Tags: c#, excel, interop

Estoy realizando una especie de programa de búsqueda sobre excel y me surge un problema al intentar pasarlo a una matriz/array bidimensional, la cosa es que no consigo pasar los valores tal y como los quiero.

He intentado usar:

```
Cell.Value
```

y

```
Cell.Text
```

Pero Value me da error al pasar un DateTime al array de tipo String y text me pasa las fechas como el texto de la celda, es decir `11-dic`
Pongamos que tengo un excel de este tipo.

```
+———————————+—————————+——————————+——————————————+
| Antonio   | 11-dic  |  11424   | =(suma(x,x)  |    
+———————————+—————————+——————————+——————————————+
| Maria     | 2-mar   |  77631   | =(suma(x,x)  |    
+———————————+—————————+——————————+——————————————+
| Francisco | 28-ene  |  52424   | =(suma(x,x)  |    
+———————————+—————————+——————————+——————————————+
```

En donde pone 11-dic en el valor real pone `01/12/2017` es decir, es un DateTime con formato.

Yo en mi código paso un valor de 20x20 al array, por si algún día se añaden más campos en un excel que **no puedo manipular**:

Dejo mi código, o la parte correspondiente a la asignación de valores del array.

```
        String[,] excel = new String[100, 100];
        Application xlApp = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application();
        Workbook xlWorkbook = xlApp.Workbooks.Open("D:\\excel.xlsx");
        Worksheet xlWorksheet = xlWorkbook.Sheets[1];


        for (int i = 1; i < 100; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 1; j < 100; j++)
            {
                excel[i, j] = ((xlWorksheet.Cells[i, j] as Range).Text);
            }
        }
```

> He encontrado dos formas de enfocar el problema, pero no sé como
>   podría realizar ninguna de ellas.

**La primera** es encontrar alguna propiedad de Cells que me permita **castear** absolutamente todo a string, pero ignorando las formulas, lo he intentado al principio, pero me daba error al hacerlo de estas tres formas.

```
excel[i, j] = ((xlWorksheet.Cells[i, j] as Range).Text As String);
excel[i, j] = (String)((xlWorksheet.Cells[i, j] as Range).Text);
excel[i, j] = ((xlWorksheet.Cells[i, j] as Range).Value).ToString(); //No me permite usar el método ToString();
```

***La segunda*** sería poder hacer el array de forma dinámica, pero me parecería un problema para después tratar los valores, ya que, necesito reinsertar valores después, por lo que la he descartado.

Comment: `(xlWorksheet.Cells[i, j] as Range).Value.ToString()` no te funciona?

Comment: Tal vez sea una tontería, pero pensaba que ToString() es igual que Convert.ToString(""), pero parece que no, me respondo a mí mismo al haber encontrado la solución a la desesperada, ya por probar. ToString hace saltar RuntimeBinderException

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Autorespondo al haber encontrado la solución.

Parece que usando

```
excel[i, j] = (xlWorksheet.Cells[i, j] as Range).Value.ToString() ;
```

no funcionaba generaba la excepción

> Microsoft.CSharp.RuntimeBinder.RuntimeBinderException

Por probar he probado a :

```
excel[i, j] = Convert.ToString((xlWorksheet.Cells[i, j] as Range).Value) ;
```

Y me ha funcionado, me ha parecido algo curioso.  De esta forma puedo obtener el valor tal cual como "01/12/2017 00:00:00" y la conversión a fecha en otro momento si fuera necesario, sería más fácil.